# Groovy: Transforming a String into a Multimap

Tags: collections, groovy, metaclass, multimap

So I have a String which looks a little something like this:

```
text = "foo/bar;baz/qux"
```

My end goal is to split this String into a Multimap like this:

```
["level1" : ["foo", "baz"], "level2" : ["bar", "qux"]]
```

I also added Multimap-support to LinkedHashMap's metaClass:

```
LinkedHashMap.metaClass.multiPut << { key, value ->
    delegate[key] = delegate[key] ?: []; delegate[key] += value
}
```

The String needs to be split at semi-colon and then again at forwardslash. Currently I'm populating my Multimap within a nested for-loop but obviously there's a Groovier way of doing this. Thus I was wondering what my options are?

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
def final myMap = text.split(';')
        .collectEntries { it.split('/')
        .eachWithIndex { entry, index -> ["level${index + 1}" : entry] }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `withDefault` on your returned Map to get rid of the ternary:

```
def text = "foo/bar;baz/qux;foo/bar/woo"

def result = text.split(';')*.split('/').inject([:].withDefault {[]}) { map, value ->
    value.eachWithIndex { element, idx ->
        map["level${idx+1}"] << element
    }
    map
}

assert result == [level1:['foo', 'baz', 'foo'], level2:['bar', 'qux', 'bar'], level3:['woo']]
```

If you don't want duplicates in your results, then you can use a Set in your withDefault (then convert back to a List afterwards):

```
def text = "foo/bar;baz/qux;foo/bar/woo"

def result = text.split(';')*.split('/').inject([:].withDefault {[] as Set}) { map, value ->
    value.eachWithIndex { element, idx ->
        map["level${idx+1}"] << element
    }
    map
}.collectEntries { key, value -> [key, value as List] }

assert result == [level1:['foo', 'baz'], level2:['bar', 'qux'], level3:['woo']]
```

Comment: Simply perfect. It does exactly what I need it to. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

My take on it, I wouldn't consider it very clever but I find it much easier to read:

```
def myMap = [:]

text.split(';').eachWithIndex{ entry, index ->
  myMap << ["level${index + 1}": entry.split('/')]
}
```

If you are using Groovy 2.4.0 or above, you could use the `withIndex()` method which has been added to `java.lang.Iterable`:

```
def myMap = text.split(';').withIndex().collect{ entry, index ->
  ["level${index + 1}": entry.split('/')]
}
```

Comment: That won't give the required output will it?

Comment: I mean `text.split(';').withIndex()` won't work (as `split` returns an array, not a List).  There is no need to scatter `final` throughout your variable definitions. And your first solution will give you the output map as `[level1:['foo', 'bar'], level2:['baz', 'qux']]`, instead of `[level1 : ["foo", "baz"], level2 : ["bar", "qux"]]` as requested in the question....  So in answer to your question, all of the code in this answer has issues

Comment: `['foo', 'bar'] != ['foo', 'baz']`

Comment: @tim_yates I misread your specifications, I thought the `;` was splitting levels.  The closeness of `bar` and `baz` misguided my eyes.

Comment: Haha, not my question, and I agree some better placeholders would have made this question easier to answer ;-)